# Confusion about @Controller @RestController and @ ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

So instead of the `@RestController` I always use, I annotated my class with `@Controller` . The fun I had...

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = Paths.SOMEPATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyObject createMyObject(){
    MyObject myObject = newMyObject();
    myObjectRepository.save(myObject);//autowired repository
    return myObject;
}
```

Produced 405 Method not allowed (whole method went through, at return)

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = Paths.SOMEPATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody MyObject createMyObject(){
    MyObject myObject = newMyObject();
    myObjectRepository.save(myObject);//autowired repository
    return myObject;
}
```

Worked well I got what I was expecting

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = Paths.SOMEPATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyObject createMyObject(){
    MyObject myObject = newMyObject();
    return myObjectRepository.save(myObject);//autowired repository
}
```

This also worked and that's why I'm very confused. Can someone explain why?

(I removed stuff like `@PathVariable` and operations on `myObject` and `@RequestBody` object that is used to populate data in `MyObject` instance for brevity)

EDIT:
Body of 405 response

```
{
    "timestamp": 1446735218918,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/myPath"
}
```

Comment: Assuming `MyObject` is a concrete class, your first and third examples are the same. Please add mord context. What does `worked`? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: From [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html): *types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where `@RequestMapping` methods assume `@ResponseBody` semantics by default*. From [`save(S entity)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-): *use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely*. This may help understanding.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's the beauty of the problem.
By works I mean I get normal 201 response with a json representing the object

Comment: @sp00m
hmmm that is interesting but why the entity I create breaks spring without {at}ResponseBody and the one returned by repository doesn't?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE (with complete configuration, real paths, something runnable, but minimal).

Answer (score -2):

In Http the errors 4XX are user errors. This means that you are not calling your service properly.

```
"status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
```

This error means that you are no calling the right Http method, youd defined your method like POST, probably you are calling it with GET.

Comment: No, that's the problem. The function will run so the mapping and calling method are correct. The 405 will be returned by some "post processing" in spring after the return statement.